# Can we run multi-process program in docker?

Tags: multithreading, docker, multiprocessing

I have some code using multi-process like this:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool

pool = Pool(processes=100)
result = []

for job in job_list:        
    result.append( 
        pool.apply_async(
            handle_job, (job)
            )
        )
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

This program is doing heavy calculation on very big data set. So we need multi-process to handle the job concurrently to improve performance.

I have been told that to the hosting system, one docker container is just one process. So I am wondering how my multi-process will be handled in Docker?

Below are my concern:

1. Since the container is just one process, will my multi-process code become multi-threading in the process?
2. Will the performance become down? Because the reason I use multi-process is to get job done concurrently to get better performance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suspect much of the confusion comes from thinking of containers as a lightweight VM. Instead, think of Linux containers as a way to run a process with some settings for namespaces and cgroups.

One of those namespaces is the pid namespace. When you configure it, you see the first process in that namespace as pid 1 from within the namespace. From another pid namespace, you cannot see those other namespaces, or the host namespace. And on the host, outside of any namespace, you will see all processes, including those in any namespace.

When you fork a new process, you inherit the same namespaces and cgroups, so you will get a new pid within the pid namespace, allowing you to run multiple processes just like any other Linux environment. Inside of the container, you can run a `ps` command (assuming it's included in your image) and see multiple processes running:

```
$ docker run -it --rm busybox /bin/sh
/ # sleep 30s &
/ # ps -ef
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 /bin/sh
    7 root      0:00 sleep 30s
    8 root      0:00 ps -ef
```

Where the advice comes to only run a single process is not from multi-threaded apps, but instead from people treating the container as a lightweight VM. They will spawn multiple applications that have no hard dependency on each other, like a web server and a database and a mail server. When this is done, there are a couple key issues:

- Container logs are unusable. They are either cluttered with multiple processes all writing to the same stdout/stderr. Or they are empty with logs instead written to the container filesystem, where they are often lost.
- Error handling is problematic. If the mail server has an error, should the database be shutdown and restarted to try correcting the issue? If you don't kill the whole container, how do you know the mail server is down?

In short, the design of managing containers assumes one application per container, and if you break that assumption, you get to keep both pieces when the tooling doesn't support your use case.

A few words of caution:

- Once pid 1 exits, your container ends, regardless of whether your forked processes are still running or not. This means all processes are killed and reaped.
- Typically on Linux, when the parent processes die without waiting on their child pids, a zombie process is eventually reaped by the init process running as pid 1. This reaping process does not pass the  pid namespace boundary, so if you fork child processes, make sure pid 1 inside the container is waiting on those child processes to clean them up. A common pid 1 process for this task is [tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini) (init spelled backwards). There's even a flag to have docker run this for you (`--init`).

Comment: I try to understand your words. So you mean docker support multi-processing. But these processes is isolated by process namespace so we can not see them outside the docker container, right?

Comment: The process isolation means the process(es) inside your container cannot see the host, they will see only themselves running. But the host will be able to see the processes running in the container. `docker run -it --rm busybox /bin/sh -c top` to see this in action.

Comment: This helps with respect to isolation. But does not cover CPU aspect. Will OS scheduling differ when 100 threads in single process container vs 20 threads in 5 process each in a container.

Comment: @Pramma That's not really a docker question, it's a Linux OS scheduling process vs thread question, and containers do not change that. The behavior of the scheduler doesn't change with containers, other than to add optional CPU utilization limits.

Comment: @BMitch Hi! I was wondering if this understanding is correct - My multi processes python code still runs in multiple processes when run inside a container, but (1) is each process isolated from others? or those processes as a whole is isolated? (2) When the container dies, the forked children processes keep running, are those zombies processes still isolated from the remaining zombie processes, or those zombies processes as a whole is isolated? I know my question may not be clear, sorry for that

Comment: @yeehaw forked processes keep the same cgroup as their parent, so in the container, the processes have the same cgroup as each other and see other processes in the same pid namespace. Once the cgroup's pid 1 for the namespace dies, the container is considered stopped and all processes in that cgroup are killed/reaped.

Comment: @BMitch Thank you! I understand (1) now. But as for (2) when I do not set an application such as `tini` you mentioned as the ENTRYPOINT of the docker file, instead I choose to use the python interpreter or a compiled multi-process binary as the ENTRYPOINT to start the container, what would happen after the first process of the binary dies? will the container be considered stopped? If not, when will the container be considered stop? And when wil the forked processes die in this situation?

Comment: @yeehaw the container should stop when pid 1 in the container exits. To see for yourself, you can try building an example and test it

Answer (score 0):

Yes see the doc about supervisor
https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/using_supervisord/

You can also use daemon tools
http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html

or s6
http://skarnet.org/software/s6/

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your info. But I think your answer is not very fit to my question. May be I did make my question clear. I have re-edited my question again. Can you check again please?

Comment: I extract from an old  Docker PR https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3090 this `Yes, applications running in the containers will scale to make use of CPU cores as if they were running outside of a container.`

Comment: you may need to specify in your `docker run` how many Cpus you allow your docker container to use, extract from the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/ `--cpuset-cpus=""  CPUs in which to allow execution (0-3, 0,1)`

Comment: Thanks. Seems multi-threading is not a problem. But My concern is multi-processing. If the container is just only one process. Then how my multi-process code will be handled?

Comment: Im no expert but I've seen multi process docker containers run by using supervisor as PID1 to orchestrate the processes.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/using_supervisord/